# Dummy head declaration

Tags: java, dummy-variable

Dummy is used to record where the initial head is.
why do we have to set up dummy head as `Node dummy = new Node(0)` but not `Node dummy = null`. (I get NPE for doing so). Don't we just need to return the head position? Why does setting up dummy with a value mater?

Comment: "*I get NPE for doing so*" - The NPE is not caused by the declaration, but by accessing attributes/methods on a `null` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to what "null" is in java, and what it means to "instantiate" an object. When you setup the dummy head as:

```
Node dummy = new Node(0);
```

You are instantiating a new Node object, which is allocated in heap space, the reference to which is passed into the "dummy" variable.

When you setup a dummy head like:

```
Node dummy = null;
```

You are not instantiating a new Node object, therefore there is no new object added to heap. Without a new object actually being created, by definition, there is no way to reference that. That is what null is, basically it means an empty reference, or a reference to something that doesn't exist (same thing). Because it has not been instantiated, when you try to reference it's fields you are going to get a NullPointerException.

Per documentation (linked below) a null pointer exception is thrown when:

- Calling the instance method of a null object
- Accessing or modifying the fields of a null object
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array
- Throwing null as if it were a throwable value

You didn't post the code that actually caused the NPE, but I imagine it is one of the top two reasons in the list above.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html